# Validate route on click and before the page-load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-routing

Within Next.js, how would I validate a route before its loaded?

As per the [API docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents), `routeChangeStart` is triggered before route change, however, I am unable to cancel the event once triggered.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    events.on("routeChangeStart", routerChangeHandler);
    return (() => events.off("routeChangeStart", routerChangeHandler));
  });

  const routerChangeHandler = (url) => {
    if(/* check something */){
      // stop the new page load and stay on the page
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please provide your entire file, are you sure that you are accessing `router.events`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do something like this: [Next JS: Warn User for Unsaved Form before Route Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064778/next-js-warn-user-for-unsaved-form-before-route-change)

Answer (score 2):

You can try throwing an error to cancel the navigation:

```
  events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
    throw new Error('AbortError');
  });
```

Also you can try to dispatch `routeChangeError`:

```
 events.emit('routeChangeError');
```